# WebStorm: how to navigate to JS source file of a package?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Say that in my TypeScript project, I use Express and a method like this:

```
response.send('Hello');
```

I want to look how the `send()` method is implemented. However, when I <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> the method name in WebStorm, it takes me to a `.d.ts` file (TypeScript definitions) instead of the real source. Understandably but a bit unpleasantly. What's the easiest way to get to the source?